# Segue To UIViewController From SwiftUI View

Tags: ios, swiftui

I am working to implement some SwiftUI content into my existing app.  I currently have a UIViewController, which hosts a MTKView for camera preview.

I have created a new SwiftUI view, which is now my *root* view, as set in my `SceneDelegate.swift` file.  The SwiftUI view loads at launch, as expected.  Now, I would like to create a segue in which, when a user taps on a row in my List, it will segue, full-screen to my existing UIViewController.  Here is how I'm calling that;

```
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        NavigationView {
            List(sessionTypes) { session in
                NavigationLink(destination: CameraControllerWrapper()) {
                    SessionRow(session: session)
                    .frame(height: 40.0)
                }
            }
        .navigationBarTitle(Text("Camera Types"))
        }
    }
}
```

For posterity, here is my `CameraControllerWrapper` UIViewControllerRepresentable;

```
struct CameraControllerWrapper: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
typealias UIViewControllerType = CameraController

   func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<CameraControllerWrapper>) -> CameraControllerWrapper.UIViewControllerType {
    return CameraController()
   }

   func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: CameraControllerWrapper.UIViewControllerType, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<CameraControllerWrapper>) {
    //
   }
}
```

While this "works," my app crashes as soon as the CameraController is called, as it seems any of my IBOutlets cannot be found.  CameraController is a UIViewController built in the storyboard.

Comment: For clarity, are you saying you have (1) a `Storyboard` app, that you (2) made the `MainViewController` root view be a `SwiftUI` view, and (3) put a `NavigationView` in this root view and (4) navigates to a `UIViewControllerRepresentable` that has (5) `IBOutlets` defined in it? If something in this chain is wrong, please correct me.

Comment: I think that's correct.  I have a UIViewController that was built and designed in a Storyboard, with IBOutlets, and was previously my entry view controller.  I've now added a SwiftUI view that is my root view, and would like to segue to the previous UIViewController, which is now a "second" view controller, no longer the main.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I managed to resolve this by realizing that I needed to instantiate the UIViewController from the Storyboard, and not in code (as I had built its layout in Storyboard, alongside some programatic elements).  To use the above `NavigationLink`, I needed to adjust my `UIViewControllerRepresentable` as such:

```swift
struct CameraControllerWrapper: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    typealias UIViewControllerType = CameraController
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<CameraControllerWrapper>) -> CameraControllerWrapper.UIViewControllerType {    
        let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let mainViewController: CameraController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CameraController") as! CameraController
        return mainViewController
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: CameraControllerWrapper.UIViewControllerType, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<CameraControllerWrapper>) {
        //
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A few potential optimizations for @ZbadhabitZ answer, for people who may be relatively new to Swift, starting with a brief example.

```
extension NotesVC : UIViewControllerRepresentable {

    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> NotesVC {
        let storyboard =  UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NotesVC") 
        return vc as! NotesVC
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ vc: NotesVC, context: Context) {
        // your stuff here
    }
}
```

1. Consider adding Swift Protocols as extensions. It can be tidier and more flexible (including being able to adapt a class to a protocol by defining the protocol extension in a separate file entirely). For example, I recently tried out a 3rd party tab controller that required adapting my class to a protocol and the instructions entailed editing several files both added and my own and I was able to put 80% of it into a separate file as extensions and didn't have to muck up my code while experimenting with the new stuff, and it was easy to remove when I was done with it.

---

2. Function arguments with the heavy typing are overkill; or confusing, at least.

   [Apple Developer demo](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/interfacing-with-uikit) shows an example with PageViewController that shows all the extra typing isn't necessary:

---

3. The original answer's code doesn't make use of Swift implied types. For example, rather

   ```
    let flag : Bool = false
   ```

   *Instead* write:

   ```
    let flag = false
   ```

   `flag` will be typed as `Bool` implicitly in that declaration. That is because `false` always implies `Bool`. Just as `1.0` always implies `Double` by default, and so on. The payoff gets even bigger when you start getting into longer class names.